# Question on defining $L^p$ weak solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, weak-derivatives

Let us consider quasilinear second order PDEs.

The following can have a weak formulation which depends only on $u$, not $u',u''$, so we can consider $L^p$ weak solution of this problem.
$$u_t-u_{xx}=uu_x+u^2$$

However, what about the following?
$$u_t-u_{xx}=(u_x)^2$$

It seems, at least, that such pde would not have weak formulation depending only on $u$.

Question) Can we define what $L^p$ weak solution is on the second one? (in any reasonable way)